# Install only a portion of the Ports tree in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, bsd, bsd-ports

I know how to install and update the entire [Ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_Ports) tree in [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD).

```
portsnap fetch extract
portsnap update
```

This brings down all the meta-data (and source code?) for some 30,000 apps. This bloats my `usr/ports/` folder to nearly a gig!

I am not going to install all 30,000 apps. I am going to install only three things:

- [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) shell
- [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)) platform
- [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database

➥ Is there a way to bring down Ports info for only the few apps I want?

Comment: Can you not install these from a package?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes, I did so for `zsh` with `pkg install zsh`. But, no I don't think so for Postgres, where I think people install that from source on BSD. I do not know how to discover and navigate to available Packages. I thought one must install Ports to get the meta-data for available apps. Even if I did know how to discover available Packages, I think the Question here is still useful. It seems silly to download a gig of data (and source code?) where someone may want only a single app.

Comment: Use `pkg search postgres` for a long list (not sure what you are looking for). The packages are built using default options but you do not need the Ports collection installed to use `pkg` - in fact its the other way around because Ports uses `pkg` to register which ports are installed.

Comment: Maybe you want to know https://www.freshports.org/ . I suggest too install from packages not from ports if you don't have any preference.

Answer (score 2):

While installing from pkg is probably what you really want, it is possible to work with a partial ports tree (In the old CVSup days it was even possible to download only certain categories)

You probably have to checkout from svn.

You will need the Mk/ Directory plus the directories you are interested in plus all ports they are depending on. So this will get out of hands quickly, that's why it is recommendable to use pkgs.